# Paste as enhanced metafile in PowerPoint 2016 after dpi scaling change

Tags: windows-10, vsto, office-2016

While automating some copy / paste actions between Excel and PowerPoint (in a VSTO Add-In) I have encountered a strange behavior that I have been able to reproduce with the following simple steps on Windows 10 (Creators Update) and PowerPoint 2016:

1. Edit the DPI settings of your monitor (it has to be the primary monitor if you have multiple)
2. Open PowerPoint 2016 and insert a shape
3. Copy the shape `Ctrl + C`
4. Paste it as an **enhanced metafile** (Home > Paste > Paste special...)

Depending on the DPI settings modification I applied, the copied shape will either be cropped or have transparent margins. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNrUC.png) is a screenshot of the result, displaying both a *normal paste* and a *paste special as enhanced metafile*.

This behavior is particularly annoying as most of my users have high DPI devices that they dock/undock frequently.

I am looking for the reason of this behavior and/or a workaround (other than signing out and back in). Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, how about using the *Remove background* option that is quite new in PowerPoint?

[image: Remove background option in Powerpoint]

Comment: This button is unfortunately disable for me (there is no background on my pasted shape). And when I change my scaling the other way and my shape gets cropped, it would not be of much help then... Thank's anyway for the quick answer !

Comment: I understand, it's probably because it's not a (regular) image.